# How to add reverse scroll functionality to jQuery.SerialScroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jQuery.SerialScroll in my website.

Everything is working fine except

i just want that when my slider finish scrolling then it should scroll in reverse direction one by one step.

But currently it  will scroll complete image at once and reach to start point after finishing up.

So please tell me how can i do this ?

for jQuery.SerialScroll reference you can check this link:http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got the answer it [here](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/04/doctorate-on-jqueryserialscroll.html)

or we can use [this](http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/SerialScroll_right-to-left.js)